# When is a determinantal variety $\mathbb Q$-Gorenstein?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $S_{r,s}=k[x_{i,j}]$, $1\leq i \leq r, 1\leq j \leq s$. Let $I_t$ be the ideal of $t\times t$-minors of the generic $r\times s$-matrix $(x_{i,j})$, and let $R_{r,s,t}=S_{r,s}/I_t$. It's known that $R_{r,s,t}$ is a normal Cohen--Macaulay ring, and that $R_{r,s,t}$ is Gorenstein exactly when $r=s$ or $t=1$.

More generally, is there a criteria for when $R_{r,s,t}$ will be $\mathbb Q$-Gorenstein, i.e., for when some reflexive power of $\mathcal O_{R_{r,s,t}}(K_{R_{r,s,t}})$ will be locally free? From experimentations in Macaulay2, this already seems to be rare; even for the $2\times 2$-minors of the generic $2\times 3$ matrix this seems to fail. Does anyone know when (if ever) this will hold, and a reference?

Comment: I’d check the book of Bruns and Vetter. I’m not familiar with the book or notation, but (8.4) Corolloary (or a statement before this) seems to be say that class groups are free (so torsion free).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me there! That, along with their description of the canonical module, solves it; they give an explicit description of the generators of the canonical module as a symbolic power of a divisorial ideal, and the torsionfreeness you point out implies that no symbolic power can be principal. If you want to post this as an answer I’d be happy to accept it!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I am glad it worked. As you figured it out, those words are more than enough to me.